# OutOfMemory Error on parsing a big SQL query

Tags: jsqlparser

While parsing a big SQL query, I am getting JVM OutOfMemory error. This error raised during SQL query translation using JSqlParser.

The below lines coped from the thread error stack:

```
Thread 0x648608688
  at java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.<init>()V (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.Arrays.copyOf([Ljava/lang/Object;I)[Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(I)V (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(Ljava/util/Collection;)Z (Unknown Source)
```

The one way to come out of this heap OutOfMemory problem is increasing the configured heap size limit.

Is there any other ways / best practices to improve performance in order to  reduce heap memory usage during SQL query translation using JSqlParser?

Comment: Maybe add a `-Xmax` flag?

Comment: Correct. That is one way and may resolve the problem. Any other way to fix  or best practices?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you've already mentioned it

Comment: Please povide an example sql. While parsing a lot of objects could be generated.